# execvp fails when a command has an option

Tags: c, shell, operating-system, command, exec

So I am reading commands from a file that has a line of commands, each separated by a delimiter which is a semi colon. I got these commands into an array and I am basically executing them one by one. Everything works fine until I have a command that has an option and `execvp` fails and I don't know how to fix this.

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

char delim[] = ";";  // the semicolon is the commands separator
    FILE* batchFile;
char oneLine[512];

batchFile = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
int numOfCommands = 0;
    char *commands[100];
char *oneCommand;
pid_t childPid;
int child_status;

if(batchFile == NULL)
{
    perror("Error opening file ... exiting !");
    exit(1);
}

if(fgets(oneLine,512,batchFile) != NULL)
{   
    //puts(mystring);
    fclose(batchFile);
}

printf("The command is: %s \n", oneLine);

oneCommand = strtok(oneLine,delim);
commands[numOfCommands++] = strdup(oneCommand);

 while((oneCommand=strtok(NULL, delim))!=NULL)
{
        commands[numOfCommands++] = strdup(oneCommand);
}

commands[numOfCommands] = NULL;

for(int i = 0;i < numOfCommands;i++)
{
    printf("The command is: %s \n",commands[i]);
}

for(int i =0;i < numOfCommands;i++)
{
        childPid = fork();

    if(childPid == 0)
    {
        execvp(commands[i], argv);
        perror("exec failure");
            exit(1);
    }
    else 
    {
        wait(&child_status);
    }


}

 return 1;
 }
```

and some commands like exit, cd will not work, I guess maybe because they are not in /bin ??

and how could this be fixed ?

My file has the following line

> ls;date;cal;pwd;cd;ls -l;

and when I run my program it outputs the following.

[image]

Comment: You are passing `argv`: `execvp(commands[i], argv);`. You probably wanted to pass `commands`.

Comment: @I3x I changed it and I got no such file or directory not found for every single command.

Comment: Post an example line for which execvp fails. Print the command and arguments thaat you pass to `execvp` to verify.

Comment: So my file file.txt has this line

ls;date;cal;pwd;cd;ls -l;

Comment: I edited it and added my output when I had the argv, but when I have the commands, I just get no such file or directory for all the commands

Comment: The first arg to `execvp` is the file to be executed. Obviously `ls -l` is not a file. You need to strip away everything after the actual command before passing that to `execvp` as the first argument. The argument list, including the command itself, goes into the second argument to `execvp`.

Comment: so how do we fix this and how can I pass the options then ( -l ) for example  ?? @kaylum

Comment: another question , why is cd not working, even by itself, execvp doesn't seem to find cd, i guess because it is not in /bin , but i mean how could I find it then ?

Comment: You need to parse the input string. Many different ways to do it. For example [`strtok`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok). And you can't run `cd` because it's not an executable file but rather a built in shell command.

Comment: There is no program called `ls -l` — five characters, `l`, `s`, space, dash, `l`; you need to use `char *args[] = { "ls", "-l", 0 }; execvp(args[0], args);` or equivalent.  You have to parse your commands more thoroughly, splitting the command and arguments at spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the output, it fails for `cd`. This is expected because `cd` is a shell built-in, not a *command*. For `cd`, you have to use `chdir(2)` instead of `execv()`.

`ls -l` fails because there's no such command. You need to split the command again before passing them to `execvp()`.

Basically, the command you pass has to be in the form:

```
char *cmd[] = {"ls", "-l", 0};  
execvp(cmd[0], cmd);
```

Comment: ok, that's informative. But how can I execute other builtin commands like echo , and could you show me how to use chdir() with a simple example.

and what is the the zero in the char * cmd, I know ls is the command , -l is the option but what is zero ?

Comment: You pass the path you want to change to it: `chdir("/home/usr");`. `0` is to terminate the array as required by `execvp()`. It's equivalent to using `NULL`.

Comment: so 0 must be passed for every other executable command like date, cal,pwd,ls ... etc ... anything that is in /bin.

and what about other built in command like echo ??

Comment: Yes. The array you pass to `execvp()` has to end with `NULL` pointer as the last argument.